# how to intercept/view a soap request and response from android device in windows 7 laptop?

Tags: android, soap, windows-7-x64

I am a android developer.
Recently I am working on a project having SOAP web services.
I am using ksoap for request and response.
But I need a tool to capture/view the SOAP request and Response on the run time.
A tool similarly to "mitm proxy" for SOAP for windows 7-64 bit version.

> Can anyone help?

I have tried

- Burp suit, but not able to generate cert file.
- charles-proxy-4.5.1-win64, but not able to install properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Profiler" do not show result for long response. 
I found a solution for that using Charles/MITM proxy (free tool).

1. First install the MITM proxy/Charles in your respective device(windows/linux/IOS)
2. Secondly, add cert/pem files in your mobile device
3. Configure proxy in your mobile phone
4. add a "xml" file to your android application as follows

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <network-security-config>
        <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
              <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
              <certificates src="user" />
           </trust-anchors>
        </debug-overrides>
     </network-security-config>
   ```
5. Save it as "network_security_config.xml" in "xml" folder
6. add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to application element in the android manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler) in Android Studio or [Stetho](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-network-traffic-with-stetho-and-chrome-developer-tools) to track network traffic from your app.
I would recommend `Profiler` if you are using Android Studio, else `Stetho` is pretty good too.